# Post Web 8 upgrade Translation Error

Tags: upgrade, translation-manager, worldserver, web8

Post-upgrade in a live SDL Web on premise and World Server SaaS scenario, we are seeing this in logs after set to verbose.

```
 Tridion.TranslationManager.Service    RetrieveFromTranslation    The configured URL https://domain.idiomworldserver.com:443/ws/services has been updated to https://domain.idiomworldserver.com:443/ws-api/v1/ for use by the World Server REST API.
```

has anyone experienced this in a live environment with Web 8.1.1 ?

It seems to be config related as i can get to tehe translation tab within updated Web 8 eclipse menu, see a list of jobs, and received workflow updates.

However, when you click on a job and/or view the translation tab within the properties of a component source or target.. it just spins.

[image]

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:

[image]

I see this in logs, after trying to select translation tab (and it just spins in screenshot above)

```
 2017-03-13T16:12:17.9755172Z   TcmServiceHost  9   TcmItem.GetPathToRootOrgItem: start loading resultCacheKey=TcmItem.GetPathToRootOrgItem.Full.tcm:78-98326FalseTrue
 2017-03-13T16:12:17.9755172Z   TcmServiceHost  9   Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetPathToRootOrgItem tcmUri=tcm:78-98326
 2017-03-13T16:12:17.9755172Z   TcmServiceHost  9   UserContext reused from tcmSession
 2017-03-13T16:12:17.9755172Z   TcmServiceHost  9   Entry CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:78-98326 key=tm:TextSegments
 2017-03-13T16:12:17.9911560Z   TcmServiceHost  9   Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:78-98326 key=tm:TextSegments
 2017-03-13T16:12:18.0067968Z   TcmServiceHost  9   Exit CoreServiceProxy.GetPathToRootOrgItem tcmUri=tcm:78-98326
 2017-03-13T16:12:18.0536447Z   TcmServiceHost  9   TcmItem.GetPathToRootOrgItem: load blueprint chain for publication
 2017-03-13T16:12:18.0536447Z   TcmServiceHost  9   BluePrintChain: ctr. item=tcm:0-78-1
 2017-03-13T16:12:18.0536447Z   TcmServiceHost  9   BluePrintChain: ctr exit. _publicationLookup length=102
 2017-03-13T16:12:18.0536447Z   TcmServiceHost  9   TcmItem.GetPathToRootOrgItem: exit
 2017-03-13T16:12:18.0536447Z   TcmServiceHost  9   BluePrintChain: ctr. item=tcm:0-78-1
 2017-03-13T16:12:18.0536447Z   TcmServiceHost  9   BluePrintChain: ctr exit. _publicationLookup length=102
 2017-03-13T16:12:18.0536447Z   TcmServiceHost  9   BluePrintChain: ctr. item=tcm:0-78-1
 2017-03-13T16:12:18.0536447Z   TcmServiceHost  9   BluePrintChain: ctr exit. _publicationLookup length=102
 2017-03-13T16:12:18.0536447Z   TcmServiceHost  9   BluePrintChain: ctr. item=tcm:0-42-1
 2017-03-13T16:12:18.0536447Z   TcmServiceHost  9   BluePrintChain: ctr exit. _publicationLookup length=102
 2017-03-13T16:12:18.0536447Z   TcmServiceHost  44  UserContext disposed by tcmSession
 2017-03-13T16:12:18.0536447Z   TcmServiceHost  44  UserContext disposed by user
 2017-03-13T16:12:18.0536447Z   TcmServiceHost  44  UserContext disposed by user
 2017-03-13T16:12:18.0536447Z   TcmServiceHost  44  TmSession disposed by user
```

Comment: That's not actually an error. The configured URL is normalized and if the URL is different as a result it logs that fact. The new URL looks correct to me. Your problem seems to be a performance issue, unless you have an error in your logs somewhere? Or perhaps in your browser? Also, you point out that this is a live environment -- does that mean you didn't have this problem on dev/test/acceptance with the same configuration?

Comment: No issues like this in lower environments.. I had performance issues with loading components within user groups that had translation permissions, but once I disabled communicator in web.config (workaround) loading components/performance issue was not an issue any longer.. and when I think of the differences, the live environment is the one that is connected to real project types, workflows and in flight jobs with world server..

Comment: Where do you think I could speed up this type of translation performance within sdl web?

Comment: It might be best to handle this one through Support, then. It's possible that the number of workflows and configured languages you have on Live is leading to a performance issue.

Comment: we also facing same issue. please contact sdl support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The url change that you described in the beginning has nothing to do with with this problem.

This is bug in TM 8.1.1

It happens when you have workflow step in World Server workflow that has 3-4 letter word in name of workflow step (e.g "Set Asset Translation Status").

There is hotfix for that TM_8.1.1.3875

Ask support for hotfix.